# onBeforeSeek and onSeek toggle child div using jQuery Scrollable?

Tags: jquery, flowplayer, jquery-scrollable

I'm scrolling some panels which contain some YouTube clips using [jQuery Tools Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable.html). I'd like to hide them during the transition to avoid a jerky animation.

Markup:

```
<div id="panel_items">
    <div id="wrap">
        <div class="event">
            <div class="header">Event 1</div><!-- Header is always displayed -->
            <div class="youtube">youtube clips</div><!-- hide during transition, then show -->
        </div>
        <div class="event">
            <div class="header">Event 2</div>
            <div class="youtube" style="display: none">More youtube clips</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Current JS:

```
$("#panel_items").scrollable({
  onBeforeSeek: function() { console.log("hide .child .youtube"); }, 
  onSeek: function() { console.log("Show child .youtube"); }        
});
```

Bonus question: How can I automatically set the height of `#panel_items` to match the current panel height (`.event`)?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work (untested):

```
$("#panel_items").scrollable({
   onBeforeSeek: function() { this.getItems().css({'visibility': 'hidden'}); }, 
   onSeek: function() { this.getItems().css({'visibility': 'visible'});}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try it like that? :

```
var api = jQuery("#panel_items").data("scrollable");

api.onBeforeSeek(function() {

    jQuery(". youtube").fadeOut(100);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

fadein and fadeout throws off the count. After some testing, this works:

```
onBeforeSeek: function (e,i) {
    $(".items").animate({opacity:0},400);
},
onSeek: function (e,i) {
    $(".items").animate({opacity:1},400);
}
```